# Teamcity Cannot add VCS root from Vsts

Tags: azure-devops, teamcity

I am try to connect my teamcity server (2018.1) to VSTS (visualstudio.com) using a Personal Access token. Now the first part seems to work. After I add the token to teamcity I am able to see all repositories in the account but next I cannot create a project in the create project from URL dialog. I get the error :

> List remote refs failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com/xxxxxx/_git/xxxxxx: not authorized

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to enter the PAT as the password and any value as the username

Comment: Entering the PAT as username or password results in a different error :Invalid server path: $/xxxxxxx

Comment: @Gluip If you have already connect VSTS in teamcity, the Create Project From URL page will show the information of the VSTS git repo you select (similar as the image shows https://ibb.co/btuweo). Can you show the detail steps for how you proceed to this page?

Comment: Marina..what version of teamcity did you use? The screenshot I posted is what I see in the create project from url dialog

Comment: @Gluip, "invalid server path $/xxx" is specific to TFS, but the repository URL in your original post points to a GIT repo. There is a weird mismatch there.

Comment: I have verified that TC (2018.1.2) incorrectly populates the password field when creating _project_ from repo URL. Entering the correct PAT into that field makes the wizard happy.